# Calculate and Use Dynamic Height for SlimScroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, slimscroll

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YK47P/45/)

I have a sidebar with 100% height. I have a top widget and a bottom widget. I want to make the bottom widget scrollable, with [slimscroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/).

```
.sidebar {width:300px; padding:10px; background:#efefef;height:100%; position:fixed}
.top-widget {background:#eeefff;padding:10px}
.scroll-widget {overflow-y: scroll;padding:10px;margin:10px; background:#fffeee; height:300px}
```

The problem is slimscroll or any similar scroll plugin we have to make the container of fixed height.

Anyway I can assign a height dynamically to `.scroll-widget` before slimscroll is called so that it works ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get element's height by calling

```
$('#element').height();
```

or

```
$('#element').outerHeight();
```

The difference between height and outerheight is; height only gets element's inline height without padding and margins. Outerheight calculates based on element's: height, padding, margin and border.

Call these after window loads.

**Edit**: For calculating margin too, have to give boolean to

> outerHeight(true);

Comment: `outerHeight()` doesn't include margin, rather `outerHeight(true)` does

Comment: -1 :) Sure. I truely tell people to kill themselves, i did not tell about how to get element's height.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to say? He's not asking how to measure height, he's asking how to set it

Comment: I'm saying, i told him how to get height of element. I did not tell any wrong information, i just forgot to add a small missing information. Why downwote?

Comment: I'm telling you. He DOESN'T ask how to GET the height of the element. He asks how to SET the height.

Comment: **Anyway I can assign a height dynamically to .scroll-widget before slimscroll is called so that it works ?** 

I think we both misunderstood him. He gets and sets, and asking if it's work.